# Dataflow not able to find a module specified using extra_package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a Dataflow pipeline in batch mode using Apache beam Python SDK. I am using one non-public dependency 'uplight-telemetry'. I have specified it using parameter extra_package while creating pipeline_options object. However, the pipeline loading is failing with an error `No module named 'uplight_telemetry'`.
The code to create pipeline_options is as following-

```
def __create_pipeline_options_dataflow(job_name):
    # Set up the Dataflow runner options
    gcp_project_id = os.environ.get(GCP_PROJECT_ID)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print("current_dir=", current_dir)
    setup_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, '..', '..', 'setup.py')
    print("Set-up file path=", setup_file_path)
    #TODO:Move file to proper location
    uplight_telemetry_tar_file_path=os.path.join(current_dir, '..', '..','..','non-public-dependencies', 'uplight-telemetry-1.0.0.tar.gz')
    # TODO:Move to environmental variables
    pipeline_options = {
        'project': gcp_project_id,
        'region': "us-east1",
        'job_name': job_name,  # Provide a unique job name
        'temp_location': f'gs://{TAS_GCS_BUCKET_NAME_PREFIX}{os.getenv("UP_PLATFORM_ENV")}/temp',
        'staging_location': f'gs://{TAS_GCS_BUCKET_NAME_PREFIX}{os.getenv("UP_PLATFORM_ENV")}/staging',
        'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
        'save_main_session': True,
        'service_account_email': os.environ.get(SERVICE_ACCOUNT),
        # 'network': f'projects/{gcp_project_id}/global/networks/default',
        'subnetwork': os.environ.get(SUBNETWORK_URL),
        'setup_file': setup_file_path,
        'extra_package': uplight_telemetry_tar_file_path
        # 'template_location': 'gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python310-template-launcher-base'
    }
    print("Pipeline created for job-name", job_name)
    logger.debug(f"pipeline_options created as {pipeline_options}")
    return pipeline_options
```

Why is it not trying to install this package from extra_package?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work.Contrary to the documentation, the key it accepts is extra_packages and value is supposed to be a list of string.